# Softmax Classifier gives weird confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, probability, neural-networks, classification

I'm currently working on a problem of binary classification in keras and have decided to use the softmax function as the activation function for my final classification layer. My current network is as follows

```py
model_1 = Sequential([
    Input(shape=(1036, 1),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])

model_1.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
    metrics = metrics
)
```

However, I'm beginning to notice that my model is **always** placing an equal number of people in the True Positive class as in the True Negative class. Same thing with the False Positive and the False Negative.

Here is an example of the output from two of the EPOCHS

```
epoch 1: val_TP: 3162.0000 - val_TN: 3162.0000 - val_FP: 1075.0000 - val_FN: 1075.0000
epoch 2: val_TP: 3161.0000 - val_TN: 3161.0000 - val_FP: 1076.0000 - val_FN: 1076.0000
```

The thing is, I have 4237 samples in my testing dataset but the confusion matrix adds up to 8474 (double my testing data). This behavior doesn't happen when using a single node sigmoid at the output.

What could be causing this issue? I have been trying different things but nothing seems to work. My labels are simple zeros and ones that I am performing one hot encoding on using the `sklearn.preprocess.OneHotEncoder()`